# Folding JSON at specific points

Tags: json, vim, folding, neovim

I have a JSON file and would like to fold it with a toggle (<kbd>z</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>) at every line with a key called subsection. I thought about using a global command like:

```
:g/subsection/za
```

but it doesn't work since a global command expects an editing function as the second argument, and <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> is not editing.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about: `:g/subsection/norm za`

From `:h :g`

```
To repeat a non-Ex command, you can use the ":normal" command: >
    :g/pat/normal {commands}
```

Answer (score 3):

For opening / closing folds (at a line / range), there are dedicated *Ex commands*: `:foldopen` and `:foldclose`. Those can be directly used with `:global/subsection/foldclose`.

If you need to use a *normal mode* command (like `za`), you can use `:normal!` to switch modes: `global/subsection/normal! za`.